# How do I get a list of all sources a compiler needs to compile one class

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

To create and load a class at runtime, I first read its content from the database, create a new *SimpleJavaFileObject* and finally compile it at runtime by passing it to a *CompilationTask*. 
The point is that this new file may refer to other files (directly imported or "indirectly" via de.package.*) that are also stored in the db and not available as classes or sourcecode-files.

```
public class Test1 {
     public de.otherpackage.Test2 reply() {
          return null;
     }
}
```

Like Test1 I would have to create and compile Test2 a step ahead, because there are no *JavaFileObjects* or classes to feed the compiler with.

So: How do I get a list of all sources a compiler needs to compile one class?

It would be enough to know that Test1 needs Test2. I first tried it by passing a *Processor* to the *CompilationTask*. I checked all attributes in the Trees but didnt find anything usefull or complete. If a class is imported using * on a package there is no way to get a full qualified name... at least not for me :-/

Any ideas? Maybe there are better ways to parse javasources?

Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: Using `import package.*` is bad practice. Some guides say you may use it for development and change that before the final commit, but I think that with modern IDEs it should avoided altogether.

Comment: Anyway, if you are using a system where your codebase is in a DB, that system should provide such a system (outside of the normal Java mechanism).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "that system should provide such a system (outside of the normal Java mechanism)"? Is there a way to get these files compiled outside the java-code?

Comment: a) Because Java does not do these things (it expects you to give the needed dependencies), that is why we use IDEs with projects and tools like `Ant` or `Maven`, and b) because the description of your system is odd and too simple (how do you manage that you need version 2.4.1 of source `B` if you are compiling version 2.4.6 of your file?); if it is a commercial product it should provide a way and if it is a homemade contraption (it feels like that) forget it and find a product (free or paid) that suits you for your OSB. I would forget the DB idea and use a more standard mechanism (v.g. SVN).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is a way to do this *before* you compile the class, then the answer is "No there isn't".  The source code, and the source code alone determines the direct dependencies.  And you need to compile the source code in order to extract them.

If you are asking if there is a way to extract the dependencies while or after compiling then there are a few alternatives:

- The `javac` command has a `-verbose` option that causes it to list each class loaded, and each file compiled.
- If you use the standard compiler APIs, it provides hooks for loading dependent classes and locating source files.  You could use those to track what is going on.
- You can get most of this information from the bytecode files themselves.  There are a couple of caveats though:

  - If the code is compiled with `-g:none` there won't be source filenames in the ".class" files.
  - You can determine the dependencies, by compilation times are not recorded ... unless you can infer them from file timestamps.
  - A dependency on a compile-time constant declared in another class is fully resolved (and inlined) at compile time ... and won't have any trace in the generated ".class" file.

But note that you generally don't *need* to do this to compile a class.  If the compiler finds that it needs to load *or compile* a dependent class, it does it automatically.  At least, that is how `javac` behaves by default.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Yes I need the file information before or while compiling. As I am using Java Compiler API I would be interessted in the way to hook in while loading classes/dependents. As I said, I tried it using a Processor, but all information I got were insufficient when the code contained several * imports. So I have not found a way to do so yet.